# AVMutableVideoComposition messes up colors (wrong color space?)

Tags: swift, macos, video, avfoundation, core-animation

I'm creating an `AVURLAsset` from a video file, then use `AVMutableComposition`, `AVVideoComposition`, and `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` to render three CALayers: host layer, video layer, and a shape layer showing a solid red circle. After that I export the video file using `AVAssetWriter`.

The setup works, but the resulting video looks washed-out. The background video is lighter than the original video, and shape's color is different from the color that I was setting: (1.0, 0.0, 0.0) vs (1.0, 0.15, 0.0). Here's the gif comparison:
[GIF Comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RddeP.gif)

I assumed the resulting video color space is off. I explicitly set the proper color space values to both `AVVideoComposition`:

```
videoComposition.colorPrimaries = AVVideoColorPrimaries_ITU_R_709_2
videoComposition.colorYCbCrMatrix = AVVideoYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_709_2
videoComposition.colorTransferFunction = AVVideoTransferFunction_ITU_R_709_2
```

and `AVAssetWriter` video output configuration:

```
AVVideoColorPropertiesKey: [
    AVVideoColorPrimariesKey:   AVVideoColorPrimaries_ITU_R_709_2,
    AVVideoTransferFunctionKey: AVVideoTransferFunction_ITU_R_709_2,
    AVVideoYCbCrMatrixKey:      AVVideoYCbCrMatrix_ITU_R_709_2]
]
```

It didn't help. (I tried different combinations of color spaces). By the way, these changes do not affect the resulting video at all (I would expect when I tag Rec709 video with Rec2020 profile the result should noticeably change?)

Three interesting observations:

1. The same problem occurred when I generated a single frame with `AVAssetImageGenerator`, but when I converted the resulted image to sRGB, it cured the colors, and the result became spot on:

```
let image2 = image.copy(colorSpace: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.extendedSRGB)!)!
```

2. I thought it may be because my monitor uses P3, and AVVideoComposition somehow uses P3, while AVAssetWriter write the file as though data is in sRGB. I tried to run this app on a very old pre-P3 laptop, but the result was the same: lighter colors on the resulting video file, and correct single-frame CGImage once tagged with sRGB color space.
3. I tried to export video file adding the original asset to the AVAssetWriter directly, and the result was perfect. It makes me believe the culprit is one of the `AVMutableComposition`, `AVVideoComposition`, and `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this? Having the same issue